# node.current is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a function close modal when click outside but I am keep getting this error:

TypeError: node.current is not a function

[image]

Here is my following code in MemberCard.js:

```
const [modalStatus, setModalStatus] = useState(false);
  const node = useRef(null);

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalStatus(!modalStatus);
  };
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (node.current(e.target)) {
      return;
    }
    // outside click
    setModalStatus(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

return (
    <div className="member-card">
        <div className="member-edit" onClick={openModal}>
          <Symlink />
        </div>
        {modalStatus && (
          <TeamStatusModal
            active={modalStatus}
            ref={node}
            tab={tab}
            member={member}
          />
        )}
    ...
    }
```

Here is my modal that I open after click:

```
const TeamStatusModal = (props) => {
  const { active, tab, member, ref } = props;
  console.log(ref);
  return (
    <div
      className={`team-status-modal-container ${active ? "ACTIVE_CLASS" : ""}`}
    >
      <button className="status">
        <ProfileIcon /> <span>View Profile</span>
      </button>
      <hr />
      <button className="status">
        <MessageIcon /> <span>Message Me</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I implement this feature?

Comment: ```node.current``` is not a function, you can't call it with some parameters and all that stuff. The useRef's function objective is to reference a HTML element inside the ```current``` method. For example, if the ref was related to an html input element, the current property would be populated with methods such as ```focus()```, and so on

Comment: So I should get rid of the useRef and the way to implement It is work with css focus() ?

Comment: Your main objective is to be able to open and close the modal right? I'l write a more elaborated answer on it

Comment: Thank you so much, I’m really appreciate it

Comment: I'm happy to help, if you have more doubts, fell free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react, there are some good libraries that can help you with modals, one of them is called [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal), you can give it a check.

If you want to implement a modal by yourself, we can follow some steps.

- First we need to define a context, because the modal state needs to be accesed by more than one component or page in your app.
- In the context, you could store the modal in a `isModalOpen` state, and add functions to manipulate it, such as `openModal` and `closeModal`. It really depends on the amount of features you want to add to this implementation.
- Finally, you make the context globally accessible wrapping your app around a provider.

an example implementation

```js
const ModalContext = createContext({})

export const ModalContextProvider = ({children}) => {
   const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)

   const toggleModalState = () => {
     setIsModalOpen(state => !state)
   }

   return <ModalContext.Provider value={{isModalOpen, toggleModalState}}>{children}<ModalContext.Provider>
}

export const useModal = () => {
  return useContext(ModalContext)
}
```

Now the modal will be available globally